# Does a where for belongsTo relations exist in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

**Example**

Role -> hasMany -> User

If I want to get all users with a specific role I would normally do something like this:

```php
$role = Role::findOrFail(1);
User::where('role.id', $role->id)->get()
```

or

```php
User::where('role_id', $role->id)->get()
```

My question is:
Is there any way to achieve that without using `role_id` or `id`. I want to just use the `$role` object.
Something like this would be great:

```php
User::where('role', $role)->get();
```

I know I can use `$role->users`, but I leaving this out, because I cannot use that if I have multiple belongsTo relations that I want to query.

Example

```php
$model->where('otherModel', $otherModel1)->where('differentModel', $differentModel1)->get();
```

**Background**

A solution like this would help a lot, if you want to rename a primary or a foreign key or if your application has keys with counterintuitive names.

Comment: Sure you can constraint your relationship, but what would be the point? In a belongsTo relationship, the  related models number will always be 1. What you could do is define query scopes.

Comment: Could you provide a real example of your needs? I'm pretty sure that your desired behavior should be accomplished with the common methods that Laravel has available.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> User::where('role', $role)->get();
> ```

You can't do this or achieve this directly. That is because you are comparing a column (`role`) to a hole object. What you could do is define [Local Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes).

> I know I can use $role->users, but I leaving this out, because I cannot use that if I have multiple belongsTo relations that I want to query.

Actually, in this case you are not making use of a `belongsTo()` relationship but a `hasMany()` one (the opposite). Again, you could create [Local Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#local-scopes) in order to keep constraining your query to get the users that match your conditions.

An example using a custom column/value search as you suggested in the last part of your question:

```
/** User.php */

public function hasRoleScope($query, $column, $value)
{
    return $query->where("role.{$column}", '=', $value);
}
```

Then you could do:

```
/** AnyController.php */

User::has_role('name', 'admin')->get();
// equivalent to: User::where('role.name', '=', 'admin)->get();
```

You could keep define another one:

```
/** User.php */

public function scopeActive($query, $value)
{
    return $query->where('active', $value);
}
```

Then you could do:

```
/** AnyController.php */

User::active(true)->get();
// equivalent to: User::where('active', true)->get();
```

The interesting part? You can combine the scopes:

```
/** AnyController.php */

User
    ::active(false)
    ->has_role('id', 23)
    ->get();
```